# Java equivalent to WPF

Tags: java, wpf

Is there an Java equivalent to the WPF platform?

Answer (score 3):

No, but there is [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) which can be compared to Flash/Flex & SilverLight

Answer (score 3):

The most likely answer is [Soyatec's eFace](http://www.soyatec.com/eface/). It supports several key features of WPF. It uses XAML and databinding, so you can apply MVVM and test your ViewModel. Also it supports templating.

Also, this is used in [Eclipse e4](http://eclipse.org/e4/).

Answer (score 2):

[JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) is SUN's trial to compete with WPF.

It can be used in both Applets and Desktop applications

You can see [this](http://socialmode.com/2008/12/07/javafx-vs-adobe-air-vs-wpfxamlsilverlight/) comparison

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Qt Jambi.  It uses the Qt framework:

http://qt-jambi.org/